# Using front-end AJAX in WordPress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to write an AJAX request as a WordPress plugin. I initially made the request to an outside non-WP server (where it ran fine) simply for testing because I'm entirely new to developing for WP. I then tried using wp_localize_script and .ajaxurl according to the WP codex, but the only response I'm getting is a '0' from admin-ajax. Here is the plugin code:

imap.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: JQVMap & ChartJS World Map
 * Author:      Jesse Dillman
 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_dependencies' );

function enqueue_dependencies()
{
    # Run only on given page
    if( !is_page(229) )
        return;

    # Enqueue styles
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jmap-css', plugins_url( '/css/jqvmap.css', __FILE__ ) );

    # Register dependencies files
    wp_register_script( 'js', plugins_url( '/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_register_script( 'jmap-js', plugins_url( '/js/jquery.vmap.js', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_register_script( 'world-js', plugins_url( '/js/jquery.vmap.world.js', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_register_script( 'unregions-js', plugins_url( '/js/jquery.vmap.un_regions.js', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_register_script( 'regioncolors-js', plugins_url( '/js/region_colors.js', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_register_script( 'chart-js', plugins_url( '/js/Chart.js', __FILE__ ) );

    # Enqueue custom JS file along with dependencies
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'start-js', 
        plugins_url( '/js/start.js', __FILE__ ), 
        array( 'js', 'jmap-js', 'world-js', 'unregions-js', 'regioncolors-js', 'chart-js' ), // dependencies
        false,
        true  
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'start-js', 'get_data', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));
}


function get_chart_data(){
$region1Pie = array(50, '#ddd', 50, '#dc7d50');
$region2Pie = array(25, '#ddd', 75, '#7a9e89');
$region3Pie = array(75, '#ddd', 25, '#867e40');

$chartData = new stdClass();
$pieData = array();

// Swtich based on region
switch($_REQUEST['region']) {
  case 'China':
    $pieArray = $region1Pie;
    break;
  case 'Canada':
    $pieArray = $region2Pie;
    break;
  case 'Brazil':
    $pieArray = $region3Pie;
    break;
}

for($i=0; $i<count($pieArray); $i+=2) {
  $pie= new stdClass();
  $pie->value = $pieArray[$i];
  $pie->color = $pieArray[$i+1];
  $pieData[] = $pie;
}

$chartData->pieData = $pieData;
echo json_encode($chartData);

die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_chart_data', 'get_chart_data');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_chart_data', 'get_chart_data');
?>
```

start.js:

```
// get pie chart canvas
var pie= document.getElementById("pie").getContext("2d");


jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_en',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        // more config options....
        onRegionClick: function(element, code, region)
        {
            $.ajax(get_data.ajaxurl, {
                data: {region: region},
                action: 'get_chart_data',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    new Chart(pie).Doughnut(response.pieData, pieOptions);
                }
            });
        }   
    });
});
```

When running correctly outside of WP, this renders a world map that displays a pie chart using different data tables depending on where the user clicked. It uses ChartJS and JQVMaps. Again, I'm new to using AJAX in WordPress. Am I using localize_script incorrectly, or is there another problem with how I've implemented the WP admin-ajax?

Comment: When you look in the `<head>` do you see more than one version of the jQuery library loading? Pretty rare that some plugin or theme doesn't load it. You could just be creating a conflict by loading two versions.

Comment: The above script runs fine as-is when I ran it using an AJAX call to an outside non-WP server for testing. I only ran into the issue when I changed the AJAX url to get_data.ajaxurl, added the localize_script, and added the add_action('wp_ajax') code in my attempt to run the request through admin-ajax.

Comment: Have you traced the call through the browser console? Is the URL correct? Are the GET variables correct? etc? What comes back in `response`?

Comment: The console doesn't show any errors. Under XHRs, admin-ajax.php returns a 0 when I click on the map, and the URL attribute for admin-ajax.php shows the name of the region I clicked like so: http://bergemedia.com/bibleleague/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?region=China. So the request is going through, but it's not displaying the pie chart.

Comment: Get rid of the `action: 'get_chart_data'` and add it to the `data` attribute like so... `data: {'region': region, 'action': 'get_chart_data'},` That should get the action being passed into WP so it can get matched to the `wp_ajax_get_chart_data` action.

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much. If you paste that comment as an answer I will mark it as so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the

```
action: 'get_chart_data',
```

in your AJAX call and add it to the data attribute like so...

```
data: {'region': region, 'action': 'get_chart_data'},
```

That should get the action being passed into WP so it can get matched to the `wp_ajax_get_chart_data` action.